# Why does this subspace need to be closed?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I am trying to prove the following:

Let $U$ be some closed subspace and $x \in X$ but not in $U$, then there is a functional such that $x'|_U=0$ and $x'(x) \neq 0$.

My idea was the following:
Let $\omega: X \rightarrow X/U$ the standard map $x \mapsto [x]$, then we have that $\omega(u)=0, \forall u \in U$ and $\omega(x) \neq 0$. Now by a Hahn Banach corollary we know that $\exists l \in (X/U)'$ such that $l(\omega(x))\neq 0$. Therefore: $x':=l\circ \omega$ does what we want.

But where did I use that $U$ is necessarily closed?

Comment: I think the question needs to mention "normed space" and "continuous linear" functional.  If the functional is not required to be continuous, then you can do it even if $U$ is not closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you used the Hahn Banach corollary: the induced '*norm*' on $X/U$ needs to be a norm, so that, in particular $\|x\|_{X/U}\ne 0$ would be important. However, if $x\in\bar U$, then $\|x\|_{X/U}:=d(x,U)=0$.

Comment: yes, thank you.

Comment: (Or.. how is the induced norm defined, generally?)

Comment: no, you are correct, we defined the induced norm exactly like that.